# Mouse wheel and delay between checking for changed value events

Tags: c#, winforms

For the trackbar and numeric up/down (amongst other things), it seems like the event that is fired whenever the value changes has very short delays between changes.

This is causing an issue for me because whenever the value changes, I execute some functions that take a fair amount of time to process (like, about 100-200 ms depending on the size of the input)

I've noticed that when I use the mouse wheel to increase/decrease the value, it registers 4 change events (prints "changed!" 4 times to debug console), and so the functions are executed 4 times. This is probably the settings I have for my mouse wheel.

Even when I manually click on the trackbar to give it a "large increase", it registers 2 change events.

I would like the functions to run when the value changes, but not to the point where a single mouse wheel scroll is triggering 4 calls. I just need the most recent value.

A solution is to force the user to manually push a button to execute a command, but I would like some sort of "real-time" updating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on what Jon of All Trades suggests..

Instead of a simple flag, use a `DateTime?`. When the event fires, set `eventLastTriggered = DateTime.Now`. Then in your timer's Tick handler do this

```
private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (eventLastTriggered.HasValue
        && (DateTime.Now - eventLastTriggered.Value) >= UpdateDelay)
    {
        eventLastTriggered = null; // reset it so we don't update again
        Update();
    }
}

static readonly TimeSpan UpdateDelay = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(whatever);
```

You will get a constant update delay, but you won't get update spam. You can tune UpdateDelay for best results.

Answer (score 2):

Have the numeric control's event set a flag.  Add a `Timer` control, running every 500 ms, which checks the flag and, if set, calls the actual method and clears the flag.  Clear the flag *first* if you want to ensure that the last value set gets processed.

Comment: Thanks, having an explicit timer is an interesting way to do it.